# Ionic2 hide keyboard but keep the input focused

Tags: ionic2, ionic-keyboard

I have and android device that can scan QR codes using a laser at the bottom of the device. I have the Ionic2 app running in the device. I am able to get the scanned result string into the input box but the keyboard is now open as the input is focused.

I don't want the keyboard to show up when the input is focused because keyboard will never be used here.

Any idea how to achieve this? I have used the Ionic native keyboard plugin

```
this.keyboard.hide();
```

But the above code also causes a blur on the field due to which the input box cannot catch the result of the scan.

I am using this for scanning QR codes

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

Actually the plugin works fine using the camera. Here is the laser scanner demo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aREIcL7Af64

The laser scanner scans the QR code (Faster than device camera) and sends it an input field (input box or textarea or any editable field). So I want to hide the keyboard but keep the editable area focused!

Comment: Do you have to use an input field? What plugin do you use for the laser?

Comment: How is your scan method? I've never used a scan plugin, but the focus on the input shoudn't be mandatory. On a click on the field you show the scanner and them save the vale on `ngModel` or `formControll`

Comment: Guys I have updated my question. Have given a brief info about the laser scanner

Comment: did u solved ur problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no !!

Comment: Is problem resolved ?  I had looking for the same issue.